# Bring up a WiFi dialog if network not present

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi

Writing a UWP app and if a network (wired then wireless) is not detected, I would like to bring up the settings dialog that chooses a wireless network.

I can't seem to find any details on the possibility of doing this, and if possible, how to make it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if this is completely what you want but it should work fine.

A useful link for opening windows settings in UWP apps is [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228342.aspx)

As it says if the app is a mobile you use: `ms-settings-wifi:`

Or for a Desktop/Non-Mobile device use `ms-settings:network-wifi`

Note that `ms-settings:network-wifi` and `ms-settings-wifi:` open up the main settings window if there is no Wireless Adapter on the device.

Try launching this application `ms-settings:network-wifi` in Run (Win+R).

An example of using this in C# would be

```
// The URI to launch
string uriToLaunch = @"ms-settings:network-wifi";

// Create a Uri object from a URI string 
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

// Launch the URI
async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Launch the URI
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

   if (success)
   {
      // URI launched
   }
   else
   {
      // URI launch failed
   }
}
```

Comment: There's no `Process.Start` anymore... `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (profile == null || profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() < NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
{
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:network-wifi"));
}
```

This way the network settings are opened when there's either internet access or constrained internet access. To only catch missing internet access, change the comparison from `< NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess` to `!= NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess`.

Comment: Perfect answer! Exactly what I am looking for. Had the profile call, was not clear on how to run that dialog. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks :) I'd really appreciate if you could mark my post as the answer if it was really helpful.